# Open Dataset Latin Verb Forms

Tags: latin, resource-request, datasets

Is there an open data set (freely available, permissive license) of latin grammar available ? I am thinking about verbs and translations alongside verb forms in various tenses and cases etc.

The purpose would be to implement a training-app / quiz-game etc. for learning latin.

As an example, I am interested in this kind of data for latin verbs: http://latin.cactus2000.de/showverb.en.php?verb=facere

Ideally, the data should be in machine-readable format (e.g XML, CSV etc.) .

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE. Your question looks a bit broad; can you clarify it with more details? Some example would be fine; references to other datasets you've searched so far, and why you think they are not good for your purpose? On other words, anything that would narrow it down and specify your needs.

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in inflected forms, you could take data from [Wiktionary's Latin section](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Latin_verbs). Most verb entries have automatically-generated conjugation tables, and all of the content is CC-BY-SA.

If you're interested in meanings, you can download data files for well-regarded dictionaries through [the Perseus Project](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/). [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059) is my go-to resource; click XML at the bottom of the page to download a machine-readable form. But L&S is written for human eyes, not automated systems, and assumes the reader can fill in all regular inflected forms from the principal parts.

Comment: And the best Latin grammar in English is online free: [_A Latin Grammar_](https://archive.org/stream/alatingrammar03buckgoog#page/n12/mode/2up), by William Gardner Hale and Carl Darling Buck, 1903. Not much has changed in Latin since then, luckily.